# Cloud Server using Python

Tags: python, client-server, cloud

My teacher asked me to implement a client-server based application using python. It's also required to have a cloud server, which obviously should be compatible with python. Any recommendations,software,help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to a client/server chat program in Python3. https://github.com/ipal0/Chat
You can put the server program in cloud and client program in your local computer. Hope this helps.